# Beer recipe calculations?

Tags: calculations

Does anyone know of a good place to get all the various formulas used to compute final gravity, color, bitterness, etc. in your beer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open-source brewing software:

- brew-journal: http://github.com/jsled/brew-journal (disclosure: my project :)  docstring comments in the computational classes in app/models.py have links to references).
- qbrew: http://www.usermode.org/code.html
- brewtarget: http://brewtarget.sourceforge.net/

Non-open-source brewing software:

- [Brewer's Friend](http://www.brewersfriend.com/) has a number of excellent online calculators distinguished by having documented details on their approach and the references/formula used.

Archives:

- "Technical Library at the Brewery": [www.brewery.org/Library.html](http://www.brewery.org/Library.html)
- Home Brew Digest archives: [hbd.org/archives.shtml](http://hbd.org/archives.shtml) ftp, but often quite a high s/n ratio.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of info I was looking for! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 7):

Hopville has a nice online recipe calculator: http://beercalculus.hopville.com/recipe.  You can store your recipes on the site too which makes it very easy share your awesome creations with others :)

Answer (score 1):

Jamil has a great [pitching rate calculator](http://www.mrmalty.com/calc/calc.html) on his site, which you might be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

The [Beer Recipator](http://hbd.org/cgi-bin/recipator/recipator) is another good one.

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of [BeerSmith](http://www.beersmith.com/).  Performs tons of calculations, maintains recipes, and all around is a handy tool to have.  There is a trial version to get a feel for it, and for me it was well worth the cost to get the full version.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [captainbrew.com](http://www.captainbrew.com/). You can create recipes, adjust gravity or bitterness, scale a recipe, create brew sessions and many more. 
There are also other calculators included like Yeast Pitching Rate, Priming Sugar, Keg Carbonation, ABV , Sparge Water, Washed Yeast.

Comment: The poster wants the formulas, not a recipe generator.  Are you with Captainbrew?  This is your second or third post where you include it in your answer?  No big deal just asking.